# Backup and restore Solaris 11(whole Os)

Tags: solaris

Is there any free third party software that can do backup and restore of the Solaris 11 OS? I tried Acronis 2017 for few times but failed. I will hang & stop at the half way of the backup process which analyzing the partition.

Comment: What are you storing your backup on?  Backing up Solaris 11 can be really easy using ZFS snapshots and `zfs send ...`.

Comment: What are you using for yor OS? Zpool, vxfs, ufs?

Comment: HI Andrew, I will store it to a linux virtual machine. Yeah, I think ZFS snapshots work  so easily thank!

Comment: Ludiegu, zpool, zfs

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways on Solaris 11 is to use unified archives (UARs).  They're similar to flars from prior revs of the OS.  Here's a quick run down of a simple use case.  You'll want to read up on UARs to see how they'd meet your needs.

To create a root only recovery UAR -- giving you a **root only** backup of the global:

`archiveadm create -r -z global --root-only /tmp/global-rootonly-recovery.uar`

To view a UARs info:

`archiveadm info -v /tmp/globalrecovery.uar`

When needed to recover or clone a system, to create recovery media for use on a DVD (use `-f iso` ) or USB stick:
`archiveadm create-media /tmp/globalrecovery.uar`

To then copy UAR to a USB stick:

`usbcopy /tmp/globalrecovery.uar`

Here are two reference links you may also find useful:

[Working with UARs On Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E38524/index.html)

[How to Perform System Archival and Recovery Procedures with Oracle Solaris 11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-091-sol-dis-recovery-489183.html)